# jquery mobile Checkboxes styling issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I managed to style my checkboxes in JQuery as I wanted them to look:

```js
var content = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical">' +
    '<div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">' +
    '<div class="ui-checkbox">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom">' +
    '<label for="checkbox-1a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-up-c">' +
    '<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-btn-text">Food</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-on">&nbsp;</span></span></label></div>' +
    '<div class="ui-checkbox">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4a" id="checkbox-4a" class="custom">' +
    '<label for="checkbox-4a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last">' +
    '<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last"><span class="ui-btn-text">Sun Chips</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></label></div>' +
    '</div></fieldset>';
```

The result is static (no action or status change when clicking the button).

How do I get them to act as a normal checkbox, changing its checked status when clicked?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you append your html string to the div which has the id `myCheckBoxes`

e.g: `<div id="myCheckBoxes"></div>`

try as below

```
$('#myCheckBoxes').html(content);
$('#myCheckBoxes').trigger("create");
```

Comment: check the fiddle seems you need to further work on styles http://jsfiddle.net/XN5Xt/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile is not only styling elements but also adds some event handling and class/attributes switching (similar for JUI, but you have JQM in a tag). So you either need to add this behavior on your own or insert standard elements before JQM starts parsing or insert standard elements and make JQM parse them again.

To make JQM re-render mobile page markup you need to call something like this:

```
$jqueryElement.trigger("create");
```

Where `$jqueryElement` is e.g.:

```
$jqueryElement = $('#elementId');
```

EDIT:
In another words you shouldn't use classes like `ui-checkbox`. You should add a simple input with label and a fieldset like this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
    <input id="foo1" name="foo" type="checkbox"><label for="foo1">Option 1</label>`
    <input id="foo2" name="foo" type="checkbox"><label for="foo2">Option 2</label>`
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I was trying to tell you that classes you've added are internal JQM classes and you shouldn't really use them. Use standard HTML with a pinch of `data-` attributes and trigger create on a container. This will add classes and behavior.

Comment: The difference is that I can do styling on the actual button as seen here: [link] (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html)

Comment: do you know what is the best to go here? I'm kinda new :s Thanks!